Remove the rest of the innerHTML text after ellipsis
The text is truncated by CSS rules text-overflow: ellipsis; and -webkit-line-clamp:3; but when the text is longer and goes to next row, sometimes the next row is showing few pixels. element.innerHTML doesn't show the three dots from ellipsis, so I can't detect it with regex and remove it.
How can I remove the remaining text from html element after ellipsis is added?
In the example the height of the div should stay the same


let ele = document.getElementById('header-inner');

ele.innerHTML = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which  ';
#header-inner {
  height: 80px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  max-height: 62px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  white-space: unset;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
<div id='header-inner'></div>




Sound much like an XY issue to me. Instead of asking how to make you solution work, ask how to handle the issue you have. In your case where the pixels come from and how to get rid of those

Couple of things:
You need -webkit-box-orient for some browsers.
The browser needs some indication of the actual height, not just the max height, so this snippet includes height: fit-content.


let ele = document.getElementById('header-inner');

ele.innerHTML = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which  ';
#header-inner {
  height: 80px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  max-height: 62px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  white-space: unset;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: fit-content;
}
<div id='header-inner'></div>



